# Duplicate certificate error

Tags: .net, windows, iis, ssl

I have webservice running on IIS 6.1, I get this error in application log  Found multiple X.509 certificates using the following search criteria: StoreName ....., I go to certificate store and do not find any duplicate , reinstall the certificate and it is same , so please advice

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , you have to go to  Certificates (Local Computer) > Personal > Certificates. Make sure you choose Computer Account when you use the Certicates mmc snap-in and youn will find the duplicate

Comment: and how do you get rid of the duplicate? "right click --> delete" simply does not work as appears again. any help very appreciated. thanks a lot